# S3: Make uploaded files public by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a public S3 Bucket, with the public policy set like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1563368389080",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1563368385984",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However when i upload a new file it isn't public by default. Is there something wrong with my policy?

Comment: What makes you think that the object is not public? How are you accessing it and what message do you receive?

Comment: The fact that it gives me AccessDenied when i try to request that file, plus if i go in Object Permissions, where is specified Public Acess / Everyone, ReadObject is unset instead of being set to Yes. Here below i describe an example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282974/s3-make-uploaded-files-public-by-default/58283341#comment102934272_58283341

Comment: What are your [Amazon S3 Block Public Access](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/) settings? You will need the two relating to Bucket Policies turned off. Please note that a Bucket Policy will _not_ change object-level permissions. It acts as an _alternative_. Access will be granted if _any_ object-level, bucket-level or user-level permission grants access.

Comment: The Block Public Access policy is all set to Off. By the way i think the problem is that i'm uploading using the S3 console. When uploading i noticed that there is an option to make the file public, wich is turned off by deafult, so the object isn't public. I guess it would be nice that if the bucket is public this option is on by default, since most of the time when you are uploading content to a public bucket you want that content to be... well... public 

Comment: There is no need to set the object-level permissions. The bucket policy is sufficient to make _all_ objects in the bucket public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
    },
```

It should be:

```
    "Principal": "*",
```

Answer (score 7):

To make it public by default you need to add below code under bucket policy of you respective aws S3 bucket.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I had already that policy set, but i changed to your anyway. Still no luck, if i upload a file that was previously public it become private. For example i have a file called style.css, wich is public. When i upload a newer style.css file, the older one gets a version. If i call that file with the version (say style.css?versionId=something) i can get the file with no problems. However if i remove the version, so to get the latest version, i get Access Denied since the new file isn't public anymore :/

Comment: how your'e uploading a file? using aws console or a using a script... if your'e using a console then you should make it public by unchecking the block public access and now goto the tab access control list and update the public access by selecting everyone and enable public read and write options, or if youre using script then you should upload file using "aws s3 cp /filepath/ s3://bucket-name/ --recursive --acl public-read"  I hope this works... good luck